# After pushing onto a queue in C++ if I edit that items data after will it affect the data in the queue?

Tags: c++, stl, queue

///
This is my first time using the STL and I have a question about the queue. I have a board class with a number of moves and array of object with positions on the board. After pushing on I need to reset the board to it's previous position but I need the pushed data unchanged. Would editing this data effect or board after pushing effect the data in the queue?

```
    board_Queue.push(dequeuedBoard);
///Move back to orginal postion 
   dequeuedBoard.moveBackwardCar(dequeuedBoard.boardCars,i);
   dequeuedBoard.moveMinus();
```

Comment: In STL, think of operations as storing a copy of the value and returning a copy.

Comment: To elaborate, if you push a pointer, it "copies" the pointer so the orig object it's dereferencing may be changed independently from the container.

Comment: Maybe your copy-contructor is not working properly, for example constructed object can get pointers to internal data instead of creating his own, and than you could modify the one in que by changing the one it was created from.

Answer (score 0):

Lets create some test code. I have used a vector instead of queue for simplicity sake.

```
class CT{
public:
    int a;
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CT ct, *pct;

    ct.a = 1;
    std::vector<CT> vec;
    vec.push_back(ct);
    ct.a = 2;
    std::cout << vec[0].a<<std::endl;

    pct = new CT;
    pct->a = 1;
    std::vector<CT*> pvec;
    pvec.push_back(pct);
    pct->a = 2;
    std::cout << pvec[0]->a<<std::endl;
    pvec.clear();
    delete pct;

    return(0);

}
```

After compiling and executing you would get

```
1
2
```

Thats because if you put object *instance* to the STL container, it will create a copy, so changes to the original object would not apply to it. If you push *pointer* to the instance, changes of the original would be applied, since you work with one object.

Comment: Hmmm very interesting. Thanks for clarifying! Must have a bug somewhere else then

Comment: Found the issue! I was solving my puzzle correctly just it was going so slow I never stuck around for the results because it should have been in seconds. Accidentally was searching a set with .count(string blah) and had put that in its own function. I assume this was destroying the speed copying over a giant set each time to search through. Pulling it out of the function and putting directly into where the set was defined killed the time and I was able to solve in less than a second.